# Weird result using `==` operator in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Im getting a really weird result using `==` in MATLAB_R2009b on OS X. Example from the prompt:

```
s =
     2
>> class(s)
ans =
double
>> class(s) == 'double'
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Six times yes? Can anyone explain this || offer a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Matlab, strings are really just arrays of characters.  So what you're really doing is comparing two arrays.  This does an element-wise compare, i.e. character-by-character.  So you *could* do:

```
all(class(s) == 'double')
```

but that would give a run-time error if the string length of `class(s)` was not 6.  Much safer would be to do:

```
strcmp(class(s), 'double')
```

But what you should really be doing is:

```
isa(s, 'double')
```